# Is there a correspondence of steps between DPLL and sequent-calculus?

Tags: logic, satisfiability, propositional-logic, sat-solvers, automated-theorem-proving

Is there a correspondence between the steps in using [DPLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) to find out that a formula in propositional logic is unsatisfiable and using [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Proving_logical_formulas) to prove that its negation is valid?

And given that the latter problem asks for less information (e.g. no need for a "counterexample" in case the formula is invalid), is it possible to solve it more efficiently than standard SAT solving?

Comment: [DPLL($\mathcal T$) as a goal-directed proof-search mechanism](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/DPLL-(-T-)-as-a-goal-directed-proof-search-Farooque-Graham-Lengrand/05bf42d06b253aefe806e78e509674fc8b562d16)